# Decrypting GPG encrypted file in gihub actions fails, seemingly due to corrupt file

Tags: git, encryption, github-actions, gnupg

So this is a strange one. I've been following the guide for [keeping large secrets](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/encrypted-secrets#limits-for-secrets) (use GPG to symmetrically/password-encrypt the file, set the passphrase as a secret, decrypt at action runtime). The problem is that every time I try to decrypt the file, the decryption fails with either `gpg: Fatal: zlib inflate problem: invalid distance too far back` or  `gpg: block_filter 0x00000008000488d0: read error (size=7858,a->size=262834) gpg: block_filter: pending bytes!`

Both of those error messages, combined with the fact that if I check the MD5 of the files locally and in the runner they don't match, lead me to believe the files are getting corrupted somehow, but I'm not sure how. I've tried committing them both via local git, and by uploading them through the web ui (to hopefully eliminate LF/CRLF issues) but no dice.

The command I'm using to encrypt:
`gpg --symmetric --cipher-algo AES256 .\secret_file.json`

And the step in my build process that decrypts:

```yaml
      - shell: pwsh
        env:
          DECRYPTION_PASSPHRASE: ${{ secrets.DECRYPTION_PASSPHRASE }}
        run: |
          gpg --quiet --batch --yes --decrypt --passphrase=$env:DECRYPTION_PASSPHRASE --output secret_file.json secret_file.json.gpg
```

Locally, I'm using gnupg 2.2.27 installed via chocolatey, and my build is running on github's `windows-2019` runner. Any advice would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working. This may not be an answer if you absolutely need the standard encryption, but ascii-armoring the encrypted file by adding the `--armor` flag to the encryption command serves as a usable workaround in my case. Guessing this is an artifact of how checkouts work on windows runners.

Comment: Sounds like you told the system that the file is plain text, and that Git should store CRLF line endings as LF-only, then turn them into CRLF on extraction. This corrupts binary files that contain bytes that appear to be newlines when treated as text. Armoring makes it an actual text file, so that making line-ending changes is harmless, but you could also just make sure you use a `.gitattributes` file to mark the file as binary.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using this command to encrypt:

```
gpg --symmetric --cipher-algo AES256 ./secret_file.json
```

Then try this yaml to decrypt:

```yaml
- shell: pwsh
  env:
    DECRYPTION_PASSPHRASE: ${{ secrets.DECRYPTION_PASSPHRASE }}
  run: |
    echo $DECRYPTION_PASSPHRASE | gpg -d --cipher-algo AES256 --batch --yes --passphrase-fd 0 ./secret_file.json.gpg > ./secret_file.json
```